# Why doesn't ALL keyword work in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    world
WHERE
    gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe')
```

I'm running this query at [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial) to find countries that have a GDP greater than every country in Europe.

The expected result is United States, China. The `ALL` keyword is supposed to make `>` work over a list. It doesn't in this case. Why?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work at least with MySQL. But you also have to exclude the countries in Europe that have null GDPs:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    world
WHERE
    gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe' and gdp is not null)
```

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't think GDP could be null. How did you get to the solution though? Is there a way to debug large, nested queries where one could see the result at each step?

Comment: They state so in the question: "(Some countries may have NULL gdp values)".

Answer (score 0):

For achieveing desired result you have to try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT name 
FROM world 
WHERE gdp > ALL (SELECT MAX(gdp) 
                 FROM bbc 
                 WHERE contintent = 'Europe' 
                 AND gdp IS NOT NULL)
```

and if no countries have GDP as `NULL` then you can simply remove `IS NULL` cond.

Hope this can help you.